# Evaluating curvature given a metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

A book I'm reading suggests checking if a metric describes a curved space by calculating

$$
R = \lim_{\small{radius} \to 0} \frac 6 {(\hbox{radius})^2} \bigg(1 - \frac {\hbox{circumference}} {2\pi \ \hbox{radius}} \bigg)
$$

I don't understand why this is better than just calculating the circumference, and seeing if it is different to $ 2 \pi $ times the radius.

Does anyone know the benefit of the limit formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to evaluate the curvature *at a point*: knowing 'there is some curvature in this region' is not the same thing at all.  A good example of why this matters is the surface of a cone in 2 dimensions.